# Question about inequality plot

Tags: plotting

I fed this inequality into *Wolfram/Alpha:*

`Mod[-1 + 2^(1 - IntegerExponent[2 + 2 x, 2]) 3^
     IntegerExponent[2 + 2 x, 2] (1 + x), 1 + 2 x] < 1 + 2 x`,

and got this plot:
[image]
The uploads didn't format properly, so I just have the image. I copied the function for the plot and got:

`Plot[{Mod[-1 + 
    2^(1 - IntegerExponent[2 + 2 x, 2]) 3^
      IntegerExponent[2 + 2 x, 2] (1 + x), 1 + 2 x], 
  1 + 2 x}, {x, -5.01, 5.01}]`

This doesn't work. So I have some questions:

Q1) How can I get *Mathematica 9* to replicate the plot?

Q2) How can I determine the x-,y-axis ratio? (It looks like 1:2, but I want to be sure.)

Q3) If 1:2 is the case, what is there about the formula that would indicate that this is a good ratio?

Comment: I have no idea what Wolfram|Alpha is trying to show you, since you're asking about an inequality in a single variable and whose solution would therefore be a subset of the *x*-axis rather than some graph in the plane. So `Plot` is not an appropriate function to try. Moreover,`IntegerExponent` expects an integer as first argument, and clearly that's not what you're giving it as `x` ranges over the interval you indicated. In fact, you'll generate `IntegerExponent::int` error messages if you try the evaluation.

Comment: Further, you fed Wolfram|Alpha an inequality, whereas the `Plot` expression you then give is requesting a plot of a pair of two functions. Still you have the problem of the errors with `IntegerExponent`.

Comment: @murray, the plot expression is from _WA_

Comment: OK, I see now, in view of the answer from @belisarius: Wolfarm|Alpha converts your inequality into the pair of functions on its two sides, tries to plot that, and shows just the plot of the right-hand side -- because it cannot possibly plot the left-hand side due to the `IntegerExponent` domain problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the comments by @Murray in your question. WolframAlpha is just plotting `(1 + 2 x)`, as can be seen [here](http://goo.gl/7QPiuw):

[image: Mathematica graphics]